# Charging Dell XPS 9500 with 61W Apple charger works only when battery is not fully discharged

Tags: charging, charger

I use a 61W Apple charger to charge my Dell XPS 15 and it works just fine until the laptop shuts down because of discharged battery. Then the charger won't be recognized by the laptop, and it won't bring it back to life.

I must use another USB-C charger to wake it up and then the Apple charger immediately starts working. Do you have any idea what could cause this problem? Other non-Dell USB-C chargers don't have this problem.

Comment: The only advice I can give is: don't let the laptop run down to 0%. That's generally bad for the battery. Plug in the Apple charger when it's at 15-20%. It's unlikely that there's another solution -- Apple stuff and Dell stuff is designed differently. It's possible that you can configure the Dell, but that's off-topic for this site.

Comment: Questions about Apple products and accessories being used with other manufacturer products are considered on-topic here

Answer (score 2):

> Then the charger won't be recognized by the laptop, and it won't bring it back to life... I must use another USB-C charger to wake it up and then the Apple charger immediately starts working.

#### Apple doesn't use the 15V Power Delivery Profile

It is most likely caused by the fact that the Apple 61W doesn't *fully* conform to the [USB Power Delivery specification](https://usb.org/sites/default/files/D2T2-1%20-%20USB%20Power%20Delivery.pdf).

To summarize, USB-C chargers and devices negotiate the power that is needed and can be delivered.  There are several charging profiles that can be employed consisting of 5V, 9V, 15V, and 20V.  Apple "conveniently" [leaves out the 15V profile](https://switchchargers.com/apple-61w-review/).

I was able to obtain the [technical specifications for the power adapter supplied with the Dell 9500](https://www.dell.com/support/manuals/en-us/xps-15-9500-laptop/xps-15-9500-setup-and-specifications/power-adapter?guid=guid-2ea7ebaa-0143-4c05-803f-5015bfcb4e67&lang=en-us).  I posted them into a chart (below) for comparison with the Apple Type C charger.  You'll notice the 15V profile is present with the Dell and missing from Apple's charger.

|  | Apple | Dell |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Type | 61W USB Type C | 90W USB Type C |
| Rated Output | 20V DC | 20V DC |
|  |  | 15V DC |
|  | 9V DC | 9V DC |
|  | 5V DC | 5V DC |

#### Why does Apple do this?

Only Apple can answer this, but it's likely because Apple devices like iPhone, iPads, Macs, etc. weren't designed to use 15V - MacBooks used both 12V and 18V+ power rails for example, while iPhones/iPads, never got above 5V until USB-C came along.  Since they never designed for 15V, why implement it?  Their engineering reasons being their own.

Without having a Dell (or a lab with test/measure equipment) to  see what the Dell is attempting to negotiate when the power is below a certain level, we can only guess.  In this particular power condition, it's looking for a 15V profile to power the laptop and charge simultaneously. Once there's a nominal charge in the battery, Power Delivery can negotiate a different (probably higher) profile.

Even [9to5mac has written about the oddities of Apple chargers](https://9to5mac.com/2021/01/04/making-sense-of-the-oddities-of-apples-usb-c-chargers) not fully conforming to the Power Delivery specification.